# Get numeric value from file name

Tags: linux

I am a new guy of Linux. I have a question:
I have a bunch of files in a directory, like:
abc-188_1.out
abc-188_2.out
abc-188_3.out

how can a get the number 188 from those names?

Comment: Get it where? Are you writing a program in some language?

Comment: Tell us more about what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (since you are on linux and are working with files), that you will use a shell / bash-script... (If you use something different (say, python, ...), the solution will, of course, be a different one.)

**... this will work**

```
for file in `ls *`; do out=`echo "${file//[!0-9]/ }"|xargs|cut -d' ' -f1`; echo $out; done
```

**Explanation**

The basic problem is to extract a number from a string in bash script (search stackoverflow for this, you will find dozens of different solutions).

This is done in the command above as (the string from which numbers are to be extracted being saved in the variable file):

```
${file//[!0-9]/ }
```

or, without spaces

```
${file//[!0-9]/}
```

It is complicated here by two things:

1. Do this recursively on the contents of a directory. This is done here with a bash for loop (note that the variable file takes as value the name of each of the files on the current working directory, one after another)

   `for file in ls *; do (commands you want done for every file in the CWD, seperated by ";"); done`
2. There are multiple numbers in the filenames, you just want the first one. 
   Therefore, we leave the spaces in, and pipe the result (that being only numbers and spaces from the current file name) into two other commands, `xargs` (removes leading and trailing whitespace) and `` cut -d' ' -f1` `` (returns only the part of the string before the first remaining space, i.e. the first number in our filename),
   We save the resulting string in a variable "out" and print it with `echo $out`,

   `out=echo "${file//[!0-9]/ }"|xargs|cut -d' ' -f1; echo $out`

Note that the number is still in a string data type. You can transform it to integer if you want by using double brackets preceeded by $ `out_int=$((out))`